# How can i remove the extension of a filename which is saved in a batch variable?

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, filenames

first my batch script snippet (not working):

```
set _WRx32=wrar420.exe
set _WRx64=winrar-x64-420.exe
set _WRLNG=rarlng.rar

FOR %%f IN (_WRLNG, _WRx64, _WRx32) do set "%%f"="%%~nf"
```

[ for every variable name (!) in the list remove the extension from the variable content (!)
  and save back to the same variable ]

Question: How can i remove the extension of the filenames which are saved in the
variables  _WRLNG, _WRx64, _WRx32  and save this filename (without extension)
back to the same variables ??

i need something like: set var=%var~n%  but that doesn't work. And in a FOR loop i don't know
how to convert the name from the (...variable names ...) list to the corresponding variable
so i can apply a parameter extension like "~n", "~nf" etc. on it.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set _WRx32=wrar420.exe
set _WRx64=winrar-x64-420.exe
set _WRLNG=rarlng.rar

FOR %%f IN (_WRLNG, _WRx64, _WRx32) do (
   FOR %%g in (!%%f!) do set "%%f=%%~ng"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FOR /f "delims=." %%f IN ("%_WRx32%") do set "_WRx32=%%f"
FOR /f "delims=." %%f IN ("%_WRx64%") do set "_WRx64=%%f"
FOR /f "delims=." %%f IN ("%_WRLNG%") do set "_WRLNG=%%f"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar version on the command line, and it appears you can't do multiple variable variables in a for loop (that I know of).

So, you have two options:

1. If you know that the variables will ***always*** have a 4 character extension (including the period), then you could use something like `set _WRLNG=%_WRLNG:~0,-4%`. This will take the last 4 characters from the variable.
2. You have to do one loop per variable, and you need to fix up the way you are doing them. The proper way would be `for /f %%i in ("%_WRLNG%") do set _WRLNG=%~ni`.

Or, look at Endoro's answer for a better `for` loop example.

EDIT: Thought of another way:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=. tokens=1,2" %%i in ("%var%") do set var=%%i
```